# Realm Swift problem to change property value

Tags: swift, realm

I implement this class and save Custom class object to realm but i not need to save in database isDataShow property. Problem is when i set isDataShow = true and get isDataShow method return false(getShowData always return false). I cant set isDataShow on true in local. What is problem?

```
class CustomClass : Object, Decodable
{
  @objc dynamic var id : String? = nil
  @objc dynamic var position : Int = 0
  var isDataShow : Bool? = false
}

func getShowData() -> Bool {
    return isDataShow!
}
func setShowData(show: Bool)
{
    self.isDataShow = show
    
}
```

Comment: [This is how you ignore a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40472374/realm-avoid-to-store-some-property). Is that what you want to do?

Comment: The problem is in CustomClass is List<CustomClass> and I have class who have array Class who have List< CustomClass > and Custom Object when i change value and need read value is deallocating  and initializes. Every time when i need to read value isDataShow of CustomClass  is call init. :( @Sweeper

Comment: @Sweeper, ignoring properties objects can be done by either not marking them @ objc dynamic (which is the easy way) or including them in the [ignoredProperties](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#ignoring-properties) list. Nothing wrong with your comment, just wanted to point out the easier way and include a link to the actual docs.

Comment: OP: the `isDataShow` property will not be managed by realm in any way. There's a problem in your code however as those two functions (`getShowData` and `setShowData `) are not part of the Custom class, so they are returning something else - possibly a class var? Please clarify the question because as it, it's very incomplete.